# Adding className attribute to the passed props components in React

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of multiple components such as:

`[Header,Dropdown]`

These are responsive react components and I am passing them to a Row Component which takes all props and arranges them in the row as shown below:

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./inRowComponent.module.css";

    const InRow = (props) => {
    
      const components = props.AllComponents.map(element => {
    
        return <element.component className = {element.className}/>; //And bind element.className that's passed in props
      });
      return <div className = {classes.MasterInRow}>
        {components}
      </div>
    }
```

`AllComponents` appears like following:

```
[
{
    component: <Dropdown />,
    className: "DropDownClass"
}
...
]
```

How do I bind my component such that I am able to return the component with the respective className.

Comment: use a dictionary/hashmap with className as the key and the component as the value

Comment: I get that but, how to pass that class into the component, can you show an example?